# Does Sencha Touch 2.0 support access to the Microphone (on mobile phones) in their Tools SDK?

Tags: sencha-touch-2

Sencha Touch's Tools SDK support wrapping your HTML5+JS+CSS3 into a native app (I assume in somewhat a similar manner to PhoneGap). It provides some limited access to mobile features like the camera. But I can't find out:

Does it support access to the microphone on the phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just gonna say no, but I think it would be too short

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?207849-Is-there-a-microphone-(for-recording)-control-available-in-sencha-touch-2

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?183880-How-to-record-audio-in-a-sencha-app&highlight=microphone

You need to use PhoneGap/Cordova

Hope this helps